# Can a child template also use a child template in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My child template path is project/sales/templates/sales/table.html.

It extends another child template sale_summary_change_list.html.

```
{% extends 'sales/sale_summary_change_list.html' %}

{% block result_list %}
<div class="results">
    <table>

    <thead>
      <tr>
          {% for header in table %}
        <th>
          <div class="text">
            <a href="#">{{ header }}</a>
          </div>
        </th>
          {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      {% for row in summary %}
      <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2'}">
        <td> {{ row.color_pref }} </td>
        <td> {{ row.total | intcomma }} </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The parent template is also located in the same folder. (project/sales/templates/sales/sale_summary_change_list.html)

```
{% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}
{% load humanize %}

{% block content_title %}
<h1> Sales Summary </h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block result_list %}
    {% block table %} {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

{% block pagination %}{% endblock %}
```

My child template however is not appearing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing things in wrong way. Just replace `{% extends 'sale_summary_change_list.html' %}` this block of code with this one `{% extends 'sales/sale_summary_change_list.html' %}`. It may work for you.

Comment: I just tried this and my child template is still not appearing.